# PLSQL Function for Workdays & Exclude dates from a table

Tags: sql, plsql

I have two dates and I want to exclude weekends & public holidays. 
I managed to exclude weekends but can't figure out how to change my function to remove the public holidays

**Got a table of Public Holidays**

```
Table : holidays that looks like this   
     DT_DAY
 - 23/11/2017
 - 02/12/2017
```

**My function that excludes Weekends looks like this :**

```
create or replace function BusinessDays(start_date in date, end_date in date)
return number is countBusiness number := 0; /* counter for business days */

begin

countBusiness:= (to_date(end_date,'dd-mm-yy')- to_date(start_date, 'dd-mm-yy')) +1
 - (Next_Day(to_date(end_date,'dd-mm-yy'), 'Sunday')
 - Next_Day(to_date(start_date,'dd-mm-yy'), 'Sunday') )/7
 - (Next_Day(to_date(end_date,'dd-mm-yy'), 'Saturday')
 - Next_Day(to_date(start_date,'dd-mm-yy'), 'Saturday') )/7;

 return (countBusiness);
 end;
```

So if I use 
**BusinessDays(23/11/2017, 27/11/2017)** the result is **3** (cause counts today 23/11, tomorrow 24/11 and monday 27/11). 
And I'd like to exclude days that are on my table holidays so it doesn't count them.... Taking the example I just gave.

**BusinessDays(23/11/2017, 27/11/2017)** the result I'm looking for is **2** cause 23/11/2017 is on my holidays table...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count work days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407270/calculate-total-business-working-days-between-two-dates):

```
countBusiness := 
 (to_date(end_date,'dd-mm-yy') - to_date(start_date, 'dd-mm-yy'))+1
 -
 (to_number(to_char(to_date(end_date,'dd-mm-yy'),'IW'))
  -
  to_number(to_char(to_date(start_date,'dd-mm-yy'),'IW'))
 )*2
 -
 (CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(start_date,'dd-mm-yy'),'D')='7' THEN 1 ELSE 0)
 - 
 (CASE WHEN to_char(to_date(end_date,'dd-mm-yy'),'D')='6' THEN 1 ELSE 0)
 -
 (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM holidays 
   WHERE dt_day BETWEEN to_date(start_date,'dd-mm-yy') AND to_date(end_date,'dd-mm-yy'))
;
```

Comment: Thx man! I had to adapt it a little but definitely took me to the right way